# Retaining check box value in pagination

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How we can make the check box checked on page post back and return the values.
when the check box was unchecked we have to remove those values
I just tried to store the values in the hidden field. But the problem with the code is its appending the  same values again and again..

Please find code i have tried:

```
var existingvalue = $('#hdncheckedcheckbox').val();
    var selectedChargeForScheduled = '';
    $('.isChargeSelected').change(function () {
        if ($('.isChargeSelected').is(":checked")) {
            $("#AutoTranReviewTab-@viewId tr td>.isChargeSelected:checked").val(function () {
                debugger;
                var item = $(this).attr('chargeOID');
                selectedChargeForScheduled += item + ",";
                $('#hdncheckedcheckbox').val($('#hdncheckedcheckbox').val() + selectedChargeForScheduled);
                alert($('#hdncheckedcheckbox').val());
            })

        }

        else {
            $('.isChargeSelected').removeAttr('checked');
        }
        existingvalue += selectedChargeForScheduled;
        selectedChargeForScheduled = '';
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your change handler, you could completely empty out the hidden field, and refill it with checked values, instead of trying to add or remove individual entries in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.isChargeSelected').prop('checked', false)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.